# Backreferencing in Python: findall() method output for HTML string

Tags: python, html, regex, python-2.7, backreference

I am trying to learn some regular expressions in Python. The following does not produce the output I expected:

```
with open('ex06-11.html') as f:
    a = re.findall("<div[^>]*id\\s*=\\s*([\"\'])header\\1[^>]*>(.*?)</div>", f.read())
    # output: [('"', 'Some random text')]
```

The output I was expecting (same code, but without the backreference):

```
with open('ex06-11.html') as f:
    print re.findall("<div[^>]*id\\s*=\\s*[\"\']header[\"\'][^>]*>(.*?)</div>", f.read())
    # output: ['Some random text']
```

The question really boils down to: why is there a quotation mark in my first output, but not in my second? I thought that `([abc]) ... //1` == `[abc] ... [abc]`. Am I incorrect?

Answer (score 7):

From the docs on [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

If you want the entire match to be returned, remove the capturing groups or change them to non-capturing groups by adding `?:` after the opening paren.  For example you would change `(foo)` in your regex to `(?:foo)`.

Of course in this case you need the capturing group for the backreference, so your best bet is to keep your current regex and then use a list comprehension with [`re.finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) to get a list of only the second group:

```
regex = re.compile(r"""<div[^>]*id\s*=\s*(["'])header\1[^>]*>(.*?)</div>""")
with open('ex06-11.html') as f:
    a = [m.group(2) for m in regex.finditer(f.read())
```

A couple of side notes, you should really consider using an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup instead of regex.  You should also use triple-quoted strings if you need to include single or double quotes within you string, and use [raw string literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) when writing regular expressions so that you don't need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: So why is there more than one group if I use `(["']) ... \1`, and not when I just type `["'] ... ["']`. I'm sorry if the answer is obvious, but I've been breaking my head over this all day. And by the way, thanks, your code works well :)

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour is clearly documented. See [re.`findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.
>
> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

So, if you have a capture group in your regex pattern, then `findall` method returns a list of tuple, containing all the captured groups for a particular match, plus the `group(0)`.

So, either you use a non-capturing group - `(?:[\"\'])`, or don't use any group at all, as in your 2nd case.

P.S: Use [raw string literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for your regex pattern, to avoid escaping your backslashes. Also, compile your regex outside the loop, so that is is not re-compiled on every iteration. Use `re.compile` for that.

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question I was just starting with regular expressions. I have since read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) completely, and I just wanted to share what I found out.

Firstly, what [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012768/2521769) and [F.J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012773/2521769) suggested, use **raw strings** (to make the regex more readable and less error-prone) and compile your regex beforehand using **`re.compile`**. To match an HTML string whose id is 'header':

```
s = "<div id='header'>Some random text</div>"
```

We would need a regex like:

```
p = re.compile(r'<div[^>]*id\s*=\s*([\"\'])header\1[^>]*>(.*?)</div>')
```

In the Python implementation of regex, a capturing group is made by enclosing part of your regex in parentheses `(...)`. Capturing groups capture the span of text that they match. They are also needed for backreferencing. So in my regex above, I have two capturing groups: `([\"\'])` and `(.*?)`. The first one is needed to make the backreference `\1` possible. The use of a backreferences (and the fact that they reference back to a capturing group) has consequences, however. As pointed out in the other answers to this question, when using `findall` on my pattern `p`, `findall` will return matches from all groups and put them in a list of tuples:

```
print p.findall(s)
# [("'", 'Some random text')]
```

Since we only want the plain text from between the HTML tags, this is not the output we're looking for.

(Arguably, we could use:

```
print p.findall(s)[0][1]
# Some random text
```

But this may be a bit contrived.)

So in order to return only the text from between the HTML tags (captured by the second group), we use the `group()` method on `p.search()`:

```
print p.search(s).group(2)
# Some random text
```

I'm fully aware that all but the most simple HTML should not be handled by regex, and that instead you should use a parser. But this was just a tutorial example for me to grasp the basics of regex in Python.